# How to fix syntax error while importing google.datalab in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to import `bigquery` from datalab package in python 3.7.*, but it is throwing invalid syntax error.

I tried installing the google-cloud-datalab package but getting the error saying ERROR:

> No matching distribution found for google-cloud-datalab

I am trying to import the below packages

```
from google.datalab.ml import TensorBoard

import datalab.bigquery as bq.
```

Answer (score 1):

`No matching distribution found for google-cloud-datalab` means the package does not support `python 3.7`. Maybe try `python 3.6`

However, you might have the [wrong package name](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab#installation)
Try `pip install datalab`

Comment: There is no `google-cloud-datalab` library on the official PyPi. But, [datalab](https://pypi.org/project/datalab/) seems to be the right option.

Comment: This library can be installed in Python 3.7 (with a version incompatibility: "ERROR: jsonschema 3.0.1 has requirement six>=1.11.0, but you'll have six 1.10.0 which is incompatible.").